# How to idiomatically end an Asyncio Operation in Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm working on code where I have a long running shell command whose output is sent to disk. This command will generate hundreds of GBs per file. I have successfully written code that calls this command asynchronously and successfully yields control (awaits) for it to complete.

I also have code that can asynchronously read that file as it is being written to so that I can process the data contained therein. The problem I'm running into is that I can't find a way to stop the file reader once the shell command completes.

I guess I'm looking for some sort of interrupt I can pass into my writer function once the shell command ends that I can use to tell it to close the file and wrap up the event loop.

Here is my writer function. Right now, it runs forever waiting for new data to be written to the file.

```
import asyncio

PERIOD = 0.5

async def readline(f):
    while True:
        data = f.readline()
        if data:
            return data
        await asyncio.sleep(PERIOD)

async def read_zmap_file():
    with open('/data/largefile.json'
        , mode = 'r+t'
        , encoding = 'utf-8'
        ) as f:
        i = 0
        while True:
            line = await readline(f)
            print('{:>10}: {!s}'.format(str(i), line.strip()))
            i += 1

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(read_zmap_file())
loop.close()
```

If my approach is off, please let me know. I'm relatively new to asynchronous programming. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See [aiofiles](https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'd do something like

```
reader = loop.create_task(read_zmap_file)
```

Then in your code that manages the shell process once the shell process exits, you can do

```
reader.cancel()
```

You can do

```
loop.run_until_complete(reader)
```

Alternatively, you could simply set a flag somewhere and use that flag in your while statement.  You don't need to use asyncio primitives when something simpler works.

That said, I'd look into ways that your reader can avoid the periodic sleep.  if your reader will be able to keep up with the shell command, I'd recommend a pipe, because pipes can be used with select (and thus added to an event loop).  Then in your reader you can write to to a file if you need a permanent log.  I realize the discussion of avoiding the periodic sleep is beyond the scope of this question, and I don't want to go into more detail than I have, but you di ask for hints on how best to approach async programming.